# Meaning of this sign ?

Tags: probability

I often see in probability questions this sign regarding various probabilities: $p(A')$ , or $p(A' U B') $ etc..does anyone know what it means?

Comment: Given that $A$ is an event, $A'$ is the complementary event. You can also denote it as $\neg A$ or $A^c$ or $\overline{A}$.

Comment: And I thought it is only marked as a bar above the probability name...thanks man.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Maybe it is worth adding that $P(A')=1-P(A)$

Answer (score 0):

$A'$ is mostly used as the complementary.

In topology may $A\subseteq X$ $$A'= \overline{A} = X\setminus A $$

In probabilty $$P(A') = 1 - P(A)$$

But I also saw something like $E'$ is the set of the accumulation points of a base set $E$.

So notation depends always on the writer, but I would got with the complementary for probability!